# How to load an m17n table in ibus from home directory?

Tags: linux, input-languages

Recently I've made an attempt to create m17n table for Coptic language. I've posted the table itself on pastebin in case there are any mistakes: https://pastebin.com/pi6ugX5K
I put the file `cop-coptic.mim` into my `~/.m17n.d/` directory. I've also made an icon and put it into `~/.m17n.d/icons/` directory. I've made the file `~/.m17n.d/mdb.dir` that looks like this:

```
(input-method cop coptic "cop-coptic.mim")
```

Neverhteless, ibus-m17n seems to fail to load the table. At least I can't find Coptic in the input method list in ibus GUI and `ibus list-engine | grep cop` gives nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation and fiddling around with `.mim` files from `m17n-contrib` I've found a rather unobvious problem with my own setup: apparently, you can't name the input table with the name of the language itself. After I changed the name of the table, both inside the file and the filename itself, from `cop-coptic` to `cop-phonetic`, everything works and the table loads from home dir just fine. Go figure.

The table now looks like this: https://pastebin.com/3LUE7RU0 I've also changed the `mdb.dir` file so as not to have to make a separate entry for every table I'm going to create, it now looks like this:

```
(input-method * "*.mim")
```